# For loop to extract a item of a sublist / python

Tags: python, list

I would like to extract one value in each sublist according to the index given by another list.

Here is my code:

```
lstb = [1, 1, 1, 3]    #give my index

lstc = [['W1', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5'],     
 ['W21', 'w22', 'w23', 'w24'],
 ['W31', 'w32', 'w33', 'w44'],
 ['W51', 'w52', 'w53', 'w54']]        


for i in lstb:
    lstd = []
    for j in lstc:
      l =  lstc[0][i]
      lstd.append(l)

Out[116]: ['w5', 'w5', 'w5', 'w5']
```

I would like to obtain: `[W3,W22,w32,w54]`

Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
lstd = []
for index, num in enumerate(lstc):
      lstd.append(num[lstb[index]])

print(lstd)
```

output:

```
['w3', 'w22', 'w32', 'w54']
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me! It worked!

Comment: Could I do similar thing to acces a nested dictionary values? Such as: 
ops_machine = {
    'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
    'OP3' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    'OP4' : {'W11':61, 'w4':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    'OP5' : {'W11':61, 'w666':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    
}

Comment: nup, dict doesn't work in the same way, there is no indexing

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
[elem[ind] for ind, elem in zip(lstb, lstc)]
```

We use list comprehension and `zip()` on the list having indices and the list having the target lists.

See [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip).

Output would be

```
['w3', 'w22', 'w32', 'w54']
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me; it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
>>> lstb = [1, 1, 1, 3]
>>> lstc = [['W1', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5'],     
 ['W21', 'w22', 'w23', 'w24'],
 ['W31', 'w32', 'w33', 'w44'],
 ['W51', 'w52', 'w53', 'w54']]
>>> print([lstc[i][v] for i, v in enumerate(lstb)])
['w3', 'w22', 'w32', 'w54']
```